# Bazaar merge identical files

Tags: version-control, versioning, bzr

I have two Bazaar (bzr) repositories that have very similar content. I'm trying to identify the differences and incrementally synchronize. My current strategy is to `bzr add` files to both repos and then use `bzr merge` to identify and resolve conflicts. The problem is that even if the file contents are identical it creates a conflict and a `.moved` file.

What can I do to stop these conflicts or use a better workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I ended up doing this was to copy the `.bzr` directory from one of the versioned repos to the other and then use `bzr commit` to identify/resolve the conflicts, then finish with a `bzr merge` between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to reproduce your problem with a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /tmp
mkdir repo1
cd repo1
bzr init
echo "foo" > file1
bzr add file1
bzr commit -m "added file1"
cd ..
bzr branch repo1 repo2
cd repo1
echo "bar" > file2
bzr add file2
bzr commit -m "added file2"
cd ../repo2
echo "bar" > file2
bzr add file2
bzr commit -m "added file2"
bzr merge -v ../repo1
```

IMHO this workflow is flawed.

General rule: it is better to sync before trying to make any changes in your local repo.

So right after **cd ../repo2** it is adviced to do a bzr pull from repo1 to sync.

Comment: Same thing happens with a pull